# Mean Square Displacement of Alternating Random Walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, recreational-mathematics, random-walk

Consider a 1D random walk with varying steps: the length of the steps is $A$ a fraction $\gamma$ of the time, and $B$ the rest of the time. If $\gamma = 0$, the mean squared displacement approaches asymptotically $B N$ (where $N$ is the number of steps). What if $\gamma$ isn't $0$?

Comment: Although I think I know your intent, you should say that whether the sign is + or - doesn't depend on whether the magnitude is $A$ or $B$. This means that the increment is $A$ with probability $\gamma/2$, $B$ with probability $(1-\gamma)/2$, $-A$ with probability $\gamma/2$, and $-B$ with probability $(1-\gamma)/2$. Thus the mean of the increment is zero and the variance of the increment is $A^2 \gamma+B^2(1-\gamma)$, so the variance of $X_N$ is (exactly, not asymptotically) $A^2 N \gamma+B^2 N(1-\gamma)$ by additivity of variances of independent r.v.s.

Comment: (Note that in particular your actual statement is quite wrong: the mean squared displacement is $B^2 N$ not $BN$. $BN$ would have the wrong units for one thing...)